# Everything in small caps with fontspec and XeTeX

Tags: xetex, miktex, fontspec, small-caps

I seem to be having the opposite problem from everyone else. I am using `fontspec` and would like only the title and section headings to be small caps yet everything is unless I specify `textbf` or `textit`

Here is a stripped down example

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} % Default font size and paper size
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Fontin} % Main document font
\usepackage{titlesec} % Used to customize the \section command 
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule] % Text formatting of sections
\begin{document}
\par{\centering{\Huge Name In Small Caps}\bigskip\par} % Your name
\section{Desired Small Caps}
\textbf{Normal caps like it should be}
\textit{Normal caps like it should be}
Small caps for some reason?
\end{document}
```

I am running MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows 7 64 bit. I have installed Fontin-Bold.otf, Fontin-Regular.otf, and Fontin-Italic.otf into the Windows\Fonts\Fontin directory.

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Your [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) doesn't produce the problem you're explaining in your question. I get no small caps. Please work on your document again to figure out where the problem occurs.

Comment: You probably need to uncomment `\setmainfont…` and `\titleformat…` in your MWE before anyone sees the problem.  I don’t see a problem with the latest version of `fontspec`, but in the notes I keep on various fonts, I find a note that “`TeX` has trouble with Fontin’s italics and small caps,” so I may have been seeing what you now see with an older version of `fontspec`.

Comment: The MWE produces the problem on my computer so it clearly has to do with my configuration. Updating to the latest MiKTeX does not solve the problem so I'm wondering if anyone has any other suggestions.

Comment: I'm afraid I can not reproduce the problem you describe on my system (MacTeX2014; name of font file: Fontin-Regular.otf, version 001.000). In fact, *nothing at all* in your MWE gets typeset in smallcaps. Have you checked if there's been a mixup with font names on your system?

Comment: When I open Fontin-Regular.otf with the Windows font viewer it tells me it is normal caps and is titled Fontin Medium. Fontin-Bold.otf is titled Fontin Bold and is also normal caps. Fontin-Italic.otf is titled Fontin Medium Italic and again is normal caps.

Comment: Hmm, the font-related information sounds fine. Which version of Windows is installed on your computer?

Comment: Windows 7 Pro SP1 64 bit

Answer (score 7):

After discovering the problem was related to my configuration (MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows 7 SP1 64 bit) I rebooted and then uninstalled the Fontin font from my computer.

I redownloaded Fontin from http://www.exljbris.com/fontin.html and did an update of all MiKTeX packages.

The problem still persisted until I noted that the Fontin filenames were

- Fontin-Bold.otf
- Fontin-Italic.otf
- Fontin-Regular.otf
- Fontin-SmallCaps.otf

After changing the `\setmainfont{Fontin}` command to `\setmainfont{Fontin-Regular}` the small caps went away but a warning appeared when `\textsc` was used. Changing the command to `\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin-SmallCaps]{Fontin-Regular}` fixed the new problem while still keeping the default font as normal caps (and allowing `textsc`, `textbf`, and `textit`.

Interestingly `\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin]{Fontin-Regular}` also had the same effect which suggested that with my platform Fontin-SmallCaps.otf is taking over for Fontin-Regular.otf as the default font.